# Копирование картинок в figma

Tags: вёрстка, figma

Для самостоятельной верстки необходимо копировать картинки с писем на https://www.figma.com/file/5rXv5Q5Jw4auNDZMEsxvD3/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%92%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0?node-id=1%3A2 . Каким образом это можно сделать?

Comment: надо группу выделять - тогда получится вот это => https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/YzwjPxM

Answer (score 0):

Копируете ссылку на картинку и оформляете в тег img с атрибутом src, в который собственно вставляете ссылку.

Второй вариант - скачать картинки и после этого опять использовать тег img, но в этот раз src указывает относительный путь к картинке, либо же абсолютный, как вам удобно.

Третий вариант, если там формат svg - использовать [расширение](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/svg-grabber-get-all-the-s/ndakggdliegnegeclmfgodmgemdokdmg) для того, чтобы "вытащить" оттуда svg и потом вставить в свой файл, но уже при помощи другого тега.